# Formato numérico en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web para gestión de inventarios. La empresa que solicita dicho sistema maneja muchos números puesto que se dedica a las manufacturas automotrices. 
Estoy utilizando una base de datos en **mysql** y trabajo con colecciones en los controladores correspondientes para mostrar la información. Y utilizo un `foreach` para recorrer la información.
He investigado y encontré una función de **php**: `number_format()` pero la realidad es que no sé cómo utilizarla.

En la siguiente imagen podemos observar una tabla del sistema, me gustaría separar el campo Amount of pieces por millares, puesto que es confuso visualizar correctamente la cantidad sin las comas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ajunto el código de la colección en el controlador.

```
$GenerarTablaPalets = DB::table('info_palet')
    ->select('No_Palet_FK','No_Piezas','No_Parte','Tipo_Almacen_FK')
    ->join('Importaciones','Importaciones.No_Importacion', '=', 'info_palet.No_Importacion_FK')
    ->join('reporte_materia_prima','reporte_materia_prima.Reporte_Id', '=', 'info_palet.No_Importacion_FK')
    ->where('Tipo_Almacen_FK', '=', 'Raw Material Warehouse')
    ->where('No_Piezas', '>', '0')
    ->get();
```

Aquí el código de la tabla, utilizo un `foreach` para recorrer la colección y mostrar la info.

```
    <div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold" >Pallets</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <table id="palets" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead class="text-white" style="background-color: #004FAA;">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="background-color: #2c7fde;">Palet No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Part No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount of pieces</th>
                    <th scope="col">Warehouse</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($GenerarTablaPalets as $TablaP)
                    <tr class="table-white">
                    <td>{{$TablaP->No_Palet_FK}}</td>
                    <td>{{$TablaP->No_Parte}}</td>
                    <td>{{$TablaP->No_Piezas}}</td>
                    <td>{{$TablaP->Tipo_Almacen_FK}}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, agradezco de su tiempo por haber leído mi pregunta.
Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Intenta con `<td>{{number_format($TablaP->No_Piezas, 0)}}</td>`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya quedó lo que quería :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso para separar miles con coma haces:

```
{{ number_format($TablaP->No_Piezas, 0, '', ',') }}
```

Más sobre number_format:

```
<?php

$numero = 1234.56;

// notación inglesa (por defecto)
$numero_formato_ingles = number_format($numero);
// 1,235

// notación francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($numero, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con esto ya quedó :)